# Plot HTTP Status Codes Grouped by Days

Tags: gnuplot

I have a stream of timestamped HTTP status codes:

```
2021-02-09T10:54:00 200 50
2021-02-09T10:57:00 200 35
2021-02-09T11:00:00 200 50
2021-02-09T11:03:00 500 150
2021-02-09T11:06:00 500 350
2021-02-09T11:09:00 500 450
2021-02-09T11:12:00 500 1000
2021-02-09T11:15:00 404 35
2021-02-09T11:18:00 404 50
2021-02-09T11:21:00 200 50
2021-02-09T11:24:00 200 35
2021-02-09T11:27:00 200 50
2021-02-09T11:30:00 200 50
```

I already managed to setup `gnuplot` to group the days:

```
set xdata time
set ydata time
set format y "%H:%M"
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["2021-02-08T00:00:00":"2021-02-14T23:59:59"]

plot 'availability.csv' using (timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d")):(timecolumn(1,"%H-%M")):2…
```

I already found a lot of samples like summing over the day (boxes/ histogram) or marking the point in time per day (point). But none of them match my goal of availability over time.

My goal is to have a bar per day binned to 15min blocks. Each block should be colored according to the max status code, e.g. HTTP.500=red, HTTP.404=yellow, HTTP.200=green (only these 3, no teapot/redirect/spooky ones, and the colors as a sort of traffic light). Y-axis is the hour of the day, x-axis is the day.

1. Am I on the right track, is this possible at all with `gnuplot`?
2. What does the `using` clause look like?
3. How is binning to 15min intervals merged into the second column?
4. How to color the specific codes? (It is not like a heatmap calculating color from frequency)

Comment: Is your question answered? Any response would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting challenge. My suggestion would be the following. It's probably not the easiest, but I would say the result looks reasonable. It uses the plotting style `with boxxyerror` (see `help boxxyerror`).

From your question, I get that you want to have a binning of 15 minutes and display only the color of the maximum status in that interval. Why not showing a histogram of the different states for each interval? For example: if in the interval there are the following HTTP states: 2x 200, 1x 404 and 2x 500. Then the horizontal bar in this interval will be split into 40% green, 20% yellow and 40% red.

What the following code basically does:

1. creating some random test data (just for illustration)
2. binning of the data using `smooth freq` (check `help smooth`) with adding a little offset of 1,2,3 seconds for the 3 different states.
3. do some table rearrangements
4. create the final table with the x,y positions of the boxes and corresponding to the relative contribution of each status within the binning interval.

In order to get a better understanding:

Example data of datablock `$Data`:

```
2021-02-10T12:30:00   200   407
2021-02-10T12:33:00   200   922
2021-02-10T12:36:00   404   615
2021-02-10T12:39:00   200   689
2021-02-10T12:42:00   200   628
2021-02-10T12:45:00   500   10
2021-02-10T12:48:00   200   185
2021-02-10T12:51:00   200   2
2021-02-10T12:54:00   404   743
2021-02-10T12:57:00   200   618
```

Example data of datablock `$Histo3`:

```
1612960200  5  i
1612960201  4  i
1612960202  1  i
1612961100  5  i
1612961101  3  i
1612961102  1  i
1612961103  1  i
```

Example data of datablock `$Histo4`:

```
        NaN     0   nan   12:30   0     
 2021-02-10     0   0.8   12:30   1     
 2021-02-10   0.8     1   12:30   2     
        NaN     0   nan   12:45   0     
 2021-02-10     0   0.6   12:45   1     
 2021-02-10   0.6   0.8   12:45   2     
 2021-02-10   0.8     1   12:45   3
```

The code can certainly be optimized. So, look at it as a starting point...

**Code:**

```
### status overview as date/time dependent histograms
reset session

# general settings
myDateFmt     = "%Y-%m-%d"                    # date only format
myTimeFmt     = "%H:%M:%S"                    # time only format
myDateTimeFmt = myDateFmt."T".myTimeFmt       # datetime format
SecPerDay     = 24*3600                       # seconds per day
myStatusList  = "200 404 500"                 # possible states
myColorList   = "0x00ff00 0xffff00 0xff0000"  # green, yellow, red

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    myTime = time(0)                                 # now
    myRandomStatus(x) = x<0.70 ? 1 : x<0.95 ? 2 : 3  # random status
    myInterval = 3                                   # interval in minutes
    do for [i=1:5000] {
        myTime = myTime + myInterval*60
        myStatus = word(myStatusList,myRandomStatus(rand(0)))  # random status
        myValue = int(rand(0)*1000)                       # random value 0-999
        print sprintf("%s   %s   %g",strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00",myTime),myStatus,myValue)
    }
set print

# functions
myStatusNo(col) = column(col)==200 ? 1 : column(col)==404 ? 2 : 3
myColor(i)      = int(i) ? int(word(myColorList,int(i))) : 1
myDayTime(t)    = tm_hour(t)*3600 + tm_min(t)*60 + tm_sec(t)

# binning 
BinWidthSec   = 900        # in seconds 900 sec = 15 min
BinTime(col)  = floor(myDayTime(timecolumn(col,myDateTimeFmt))/BinWidthSec)*BinWidthSec

set table $Histo1
    set format x "%.0f"
    plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myDateFmt)+BinTime(1)):(1) smooth freq
    plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myDateFmt)+BinTime(1)+myStatusNo(2)):(1) smooth freq
set table $Histo2
    plot $Histo1 u (sprintf("%.0f",$1)):2 w table   # remove empty lines etc.
set table $Histo3
    set format x "%.0f"
    plot $Histo2 u 1:2 smooth freq                  # sort the events by time
unset table

# create final table
myX(col1,col2) = int(column(col1))%4==0 ? (Sum=0.0, Total=column(col2),"NaN") : \
                 strftime(myDateFmt,column(col1))
myXRelStart(col1,col2) = Sum/Total
myXRelEnd(col1,col2) = int(column(col1))%4==0 ? NaN : (Sum=Sum+column(col2), Sum/Total)
BinTimeT(col) = strftime("%H:%M",column(col))

set table $Histo4
    plot $Histo3 u (sprintf("% 10s % 5g % 5g % 7s % 3d", \
         myX(1,2), myXRelStart(1,2), myXRelEnd(1,2), BinTimeT(1), tm_sec($1))) w table
unset table

# plot settings
set format x "%d.%m." timedate
set format y "%H:%M" timedate
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
set yrange [0:SecPerDay]
set tics out
set key out title "HTTP status"

plot $Histo4 u (timecolumn(1,myDateFmt)+($3+$2)/2*SecPerDay) : \
               (timecolumn(4,myTimeFmt)+BinWidthSec/2) : \
               (($3-$2)/2*SecPerDay) : (BinWidthSec/2.):(myColor($5)) \
               w boxxy lc rgb var notitle, \
     for [i=1:3] keyentry w boxes lc rgb myColor(i) title word(myStatusList,i)

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like the following.

- `timecolumn(1,"%H-%M")` does not extract hour and minute from timestrings like `"2021-02-08T12:34:56"`. As far as I   know, first we have to extract the `12:34` part and then convert this to hours and minutes:

  `strptime("%H:%M", strcol(1)[12:17])`
- timestamps are internally stored as seconds, so binning into 15 minute (= 900 second) bins can be reached by using    integer division: `int(<seconds>)/900*900.0`
- A gnuplot command like `plot "a.dat" using 1:(<expression>, value)` evaluates expression and plots value. This is used to ...
- "manually" select the max value within a bin. The script goes through all points within a bin and remembers the max   value. Please read `help ternary`. I use the ternary operator twice: once for checking the bin and once for checking the max value
- for color, please read `help set palette`

This is the complete script:

```
set xdata time
set ydata time
set format y "%H:%M"
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["2021-02-08T00:00:00":"2021-02-14T23:59:59"]

set palette defined (200 "green", 400 "yellow", 500 "red")
unset colorbox

bin = 0
bin_before = 0
max_value = 0


plot 'availability.csv' using \
          (timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d")):\
          (bin = (int(strptime("%H:%M", strcol(1)[12:17]))/900*900), bin):\
          (y = $2, bin == bin_before ? (y>max_value ? max_value = y : max_value = max_value) \
                                     : (max_value = y, bin_before = bin), max_value )  \
          linecolor palette pt 5 ps 2 notitle
```

This is the result:

[image: max status code by 15 minute bins]

I think we are not finished, one should add a legend, and it might be interesting to check the possibilities with `splot` and `pm3d`.